# Conditions on a Module Implied by $\mathrm{Ext}^1 = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. If $M$ is projective, and in particular if $M$ is free, then it is not hard to see that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(M,R) = 0$. Is there some kind of converse to this statement? In other words, what can we say about the module $M$ given that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(M,R) = 0$?

Comment: It is worth pointing out the notion of tiliting (or quasi-tilting) module, which involves a condition of vanishing of Ext^1, is very relevant in representation theory. These modules are in general not projective.

Comment: We can say that the projective dimension of $M$ is not $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the converse is given as follows. An $R$-module $M$ is projective if and only if $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R(M,N)=0$ for *all* $R$-modules $N$. If we only have $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R(M,R)=0$, this need not be true. Sometimes it is undecidable, for example consider $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and a $\Bbb{Z}$-module $M$ with $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\Bbb{Z}}(M,\Bbb{Z})=0$ ([Whitehead problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem)).

Comment: Wow, I'm quite surprised by the fact that the Whitehead problem is undecidable! Do you happen to know if one can say anything about the Whitehead problem in the case where $M$ is finitely generated?

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan If you are referring to $M$ finitely generated *abelian group*, then $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\Bbb{Z}}(M,\Bbb{Z})=0$ implies that $M$ is free.